# Load module from specific place (magento)

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am trying to override a core module on the Magento Platform.

This is absolutly no problem. 
I've made a simple module for it and it's loaded by default through the etc/modules/...xml file. But what I would like is to:

**Call the module only on category pages.**

Does anybody know if it is possible to call (define, set) a module from a template file?

How can I get it to load only on a particlar template file, or only on the category pages in that matter?

---

I am currently trying things out, but still cant wrap my fingers around the right code.
I think an if/else statement is right for the core module currency.php, but mayby you guys can help me out.

**This is what I was thinking, see the order not the code ;) **

```
<?php
class MyCompany_ConstPrice_Model_Currency extends Mage_Directory_Model_Currency
{
public function __A_NAME_() 
if(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'catalog') :
elseif:
$this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getBase()); 

Rest of code....
?>
```

Comment: I strongly doubt this is possible, all modules are loaded together before any of them are used to work out which templates to load or even to deduce which page is being requested. There are, of course, many ways in which certain blocks are only loaded on category pages.

Comment: Hmmm thats too bad, so it isnt't possible to override for example the Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php only for the category pages and show a different price layout?

Comment: Your currency override class could check whether `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'catalog'` and only then produce it's new price. Otherwise call the parent/original method to show the old price. I'm uncomfortable with having different formats depending on the page, customers aren't going to know which page matters and being inconsistent is bad UI.

Comment: So how do I go about that? Do I set the request with an if/else statement to output the currency.php?

This file starts with the following: <?php class Mage_Directory_Model_Currency extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To provide an override you first need to rewrite the class alias.

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <directory>
                <rewrite>
                    <currency>MyCompany_ConstPrice_Model_Currency</currency>
                </rewrite>
            </directory>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Now you can do the actual override.

```
<?php

class MyCompany_ConstPrice_Model_Currency extends Mage_Directory_Model_Currency
{

    public function getCode()
    {
        if ((Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName() == 'catalog')
         && (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'category')) {
            // return something here...
        }
        // else not a category page
        return parent::getCode();
    }
}
```

<sub>NB: I use `getCode()` as the example because it's the first function declared.</sub>